# C++/CLI: Change Property of a dynamically added control at Runtime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have seen it working with C# but not in Visual C++ 2015

```
System::Windows::Forms::Label^ mylabel= (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
mylabel->Name = L"pole";
mylabel->Text = "Hello";
this->Controls->Add(mylabel);
```

Note that mylabel is a temporary variable here. 
Now the code work for C#

```
Control cc = this.Controls.Find("pole", true).First();
cc.text="New";
```

And I've tried this as there is no .First() or ->first(),

```
Control^ x = this->Controls->Find(L"pole", true);
```

and definitely an error shows

```
`cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::Control ^, 1> ^" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "System::Windows::Forms::Control ^`"
```

How can I get that object as Control in runtime?

Comment: `array<Control^>^ x = ....`  Winforms makes no guarantee that control names are unique, so you get an array.  Hopefully it is the first element in the array, x[0].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Find method returns an array.  In your C# example you call First() which returns the first item in the array (returning a reference to the Control).  In the C++ example you do not call First() or do anything to retrieve a single item.  That is why the error message indicates that you can't convert and array (note cli::array in error) to a Control reference.

Comment: actually there is no first() there. So I was confused what alternative I can use there.

Comment: First is an extension method.  In C# calling an extension method uses the same syntax as a regular method call.  In C++ (I think) that you need to call the extension method explicitly like any other static method (i.e. System.Linq.Enumerable.First(this->Controls->Find(L"pole", true));.  Alternatively you might be able to just use this->Controls->Find(L"pole", true)[0]; but it has been a while since I used managed C++ and I'm not sure.